# How do I exclude a clicked item and all its parents from a jquery selector?

Tags: jquery

In my jquery script I am trying to exclude an item and all of its parent from a selector:

`$(".Navigation-list--dropdown").not($(this).parent()).addClass('is-hidden');`

But it's not working, does anyone know why?

This is the full script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // When a dropdown trigger is clicked
  $('.Navigation-link--dropdownTrigger').click(function(e) {
    // If its sibling dropdown list is hidden
    if( $(this).siblings('.Navigation-list--dropdown').hasClass('is-hidden') ){
      // Hide all other dropdown lists, except the clicked list and its parents
      $(".Navigation-list--dropdown").not($(this).parent()).addClass('is-hidden');
      // unhide only the dropdown whose trigger was clicked
      $(this).siblings('.Navigation-list--dropdown').removeClass('is-hidden'); 
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude `this` and all its parents, first call [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to obtain the full chain of ancestors, then apply [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) to add the original element (i.e. `this`) back into the set:

```
$(".Navigation-list--dropdown")
    .not($(this).parents().addBack())
    .addClass("is-hidden");
```